# PDO prepared statement in PHP using associative arrays yields wrong results

Tags: php, pdo, associative-array, insert-update

I am working on a very small PHP and MySQL application. I have a class called User for manipulating user data in the database which contains a createUser method as shown below:-

```
/**
* Creates a new user record in the users table for a new user
*   
* @return void
*/
public function createUser($user_id, $user_name, $location_id) {

    // query to execute
    $query = "INSERT INTO 
                      users(user_id,user_name,location_id)
                      VALUES(:id,:name,:location)";

    // query parameters
    $parameters = array (
        ':id' => $user_id,
        ':name' => $user_name,
        ':location' => $location_id
    );

    $databaseInteractions = new DatabaseInteractions();
    $databaseInteractions->executeUpdate($this->_connection, $query, $parameters);

}
```

I have another class that will contain common methods for interacting with the database called DatabaseInteractions as shown in the above code. This class contains a method called executeUpdate for executing DML queries as shown below:-

```
/**
 * A function for executing DML queries using a prepared statement
 * @param $connection The database connection object
 * @param $query The dml query to be executed
 * @param $parameters The input parameters for the query as a hash 
 */
public function executeUpdate($connection,$query, $parameters) {

    if ($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {

        //bind query parameters
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
        }
        //begin transaction
        $connection->beginTransaction();

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        //commit transaction
        $connection->commit();
    }
}
```

When i call the createUser method in the User class as shown below,

```
$user->createUser(3,"NewUser",1);
```

The values inserted in the database are as follows:-

```
   user_id   user_name  location_id
    1              1             1
```

I spent some time debugging the code but still can't seem to find the reason why this is happening. user_id is the PK and is an int. user_name is varchar and location_id is FK and is int.

I am a Java developer and new to PHP so any inputs related to php naming conventions, coding standards, etc are always welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: reference semantics gotcha.

The second parameter of [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is passed by reference:

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was use to prepare the
>   statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as
>   a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that
>   PDOStatement::execute() is called.

Therefore, when the statement is executed all three parameters will evaluate to whatever the last value of `$value` was -- in this case, `1`.

To solve the problem, use the optional parameter of [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead of explicitly binding the parameters:

```
public function executeUpdate($connection,$query, $parameters) {
    if ($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
        $connection->beginTransaction();

        $stmt->execute($parameters);
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        //commit transaction
        $connection->commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. If I wanted to use the bindParam function, do I have to use &$value as the second parameter instead of just $value?

Comment: @bot: No, the `&` would simply be redundant. If you want to use `bindParam` you would have to explicitly write `$parameters[$key]` instead of `$value` -- which kind of makes the `foreach` look silly, and is a prime candidate for getting "fixed" the next time someone reviews that code.

Comment: Should have used some common sense before thinking of appending the &. Thanks for the tip..

Comment: You should be able to edit the `foreach` statement to pass the original reference. `foreach ($parameters as $key => &$value)`